# Module RCTLog is not a registered callable module, Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module, Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-modules, react-native-unimodules

I followed [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup) tutorial to create my react native library with Native Module. I need to use a mobile SDK developed from BROTHER to use their printers in one of my REACT-NATIVE app.

The library that I wrote works great, and I'm able also to test in the example app that the automatic tool creates.

Now I want to use this library in my REACT-NATIVE app, and I followed these steps:

1. in the path of my react native app i wrote npm install ;
2. in my app I call my library with `import MyLibrary from '...name of my library...'`  without using it inside my component, just import only to try if there is some error;

The result is that my app start and is blocked with white screen and in the log of XCode I receive the following errors that are in loop:
[image]

and

[image]

I tried to delete metro cache, remove node_modules, reinstall pods...nothing helped me.
If I remove the line `import MyLibrary from '...name of my library...'` my app works.
There is some problem in the way I have to link my local library to my react-native app.

I started my react-native app with EXPO and after I ejected it.

react: 16.13.1
react-native: 0.63.4
npm: 7.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I should only create a Swift file and a Bridge header file in the React app where I want to add my Native Module. This is because I developed the Native Module with Swift.